# Ionic 3: keyboard hiding the inputs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm working with **Ionic 3** in a project, and after I finished the frontEnd I notice that when I click on input, the keyboard overlaps the ionic webview, instead resize it to show the content correctly, so the user can't see what he typing.

here is my **config.xml**

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" />
<preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="native" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Someone already had this problem before?

Thanks for help!

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Keyboars resize mode prefence is for iphone not android, your problem is in adjustPan, in default it should be to show keyboard under input , i will send link in another comment so you could get in clear vision of keyboard plugin.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/keyboard

Comment: @MostafaHarb Thanks! I already have this plugin instaled and configurated on my config.xml with: <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" /> and still no t work

Comment: No it should be removed i mean, the default one is adjustResize which will make keboard under input.

Comment: @MostafaHarb I just removed that line, and still not work =(

Comment: Go to platforms/android/app/src/androidManifest.xml and go to line activity android:configChanges at its end u'll find android:windowsoftInputMode="set it to adjustResize"

Comment: @MostafaHarb Thank you again! I just did it, but when I saw the file, this item was already set for this configuration: "adjustResize"

Comment: Is this problem appearing just in login page or in all pages that have input?

Comment: @MostafaHarb all pages

Comment: Ok re-go to androidManifest to the line i told you and change it with adjustPan. Still don't know whats going on with your project but it should work.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Still not work. I just updated the question with this line of code on my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Look, in all my ionic projects i keep it adjustResize,only in one project i've done it adjustResize and that was because i added keyboard plugin but it caused me much work using css to enhance the view, keyboard plugin causes problems till now at least tested in normal cordova but i don't know if it works good with enterprise. So my advice to you if its not being saved is to change some css of page like view position(fixed/absolute) and work with content for scroll , so whenever field is in focus ,view scrolls down 42px or whatever. But making this is bad but could solve your problem.

Comment: As a final advice , go to keyboard documention and install or downgrade keyboard since it could be from the keyboard itself.